# GroovyScript Read from file and save in Property

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm trying to read content from a file and then save it in a property in SoapUi.

What the file looks like (test.txt):

```
1231434324
1231414144
2413131231
4142131231
2131231231
```

My code:

```
File files = new File("/Temp/test.txt") // File
def lines = files.readLines(); // 

lines.each  { 
System.out.println it
 testRunner.testCase.testSteps["Properties"].setPropertyValue( "test", it )
};
```

For some reason it is only saving the last value (1231434324) in the property.

The below example actually saves all the values to the property but it also inserts square brackets in the beginning and at the end of the property value.

[123123123123, 123124234353, 231231231241, 213123123123]

```
File files = new File("/Temp/test.txt")
def lines = files.readLines();
testRunner.testCase.testSteps["Properties"].setPropertyValue( "test",        "$lines" )
```

Comment: Are you sure it's setting the first?  because you're setting the same property over and over.... it looks like it is probably just ending up with the last one set.

Comment: @BZ Yes you are correct It only saves the last value.

Comment: What do you want saved in the property? Do you want a string with all of the values in the file? Do you want a list of each line?

Comment: @BZ Everything in one line

Comment: Do you need them to be comma-separated?

Comment: If you post an example of the exact output you are expecting from the example file you provided, I can modify my answer if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the entire file contents into a String first, then set it all at once:

```
String value = new File('/Temp/test.txt').text
testRunner.testCase.testSteps['Properties'].setPropertyValue('test', value)
```

**UPDATE**

To get the total lines of the file, you could do this:

```
int count = value.split('\n').size()
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Is also possible to get the count(number of lines) ?